# How can I pin pods of a statefulset to a specific availibility zones

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to understand, if it is possible ( and how ) to pin pods of statefulsets to specific availibility zones. In the example above I would like to explicitly configure, that elastic pod 1 runs in availibility zone 1, pod 2 in availibility zone 2 and so forth. I also don't want the pods to run outside of their availibility zones, if one goes down.

I read this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/) on the matter. If I understand it correctly, I can only specify, that a statefulset shouldn't run it's pods in the same availibility zone, but not, that it always runs the pod in a specific availibility zone.

Thanks to anyone who can educate me in this matter.

[aws overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83gTN.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Pod Topology Spread](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/) constraints.

> topology spread constraints control how Pods are spread across your
> cluster among failure-domains such as regions, zones, nodes, and other
> user-defined topology domains. This can help to achieve high
> availability as well as efficient resource utilization.

Taking the example from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/#example-one-topologyspreadconstraint)

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mypod
  labels:
    foo: bar
spec:
  topologySpreadConstraints:
  - maxSkew: 1
    topologyKey: zone
    whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
    labelSelector:
      matchLabels:
        foo: bar
  containers:
  - name: pause
    image: k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1
```